# Evaluate table of interpolated function

Tags: function-construction, list-manipulation, interpolation

I have a table (Vector), where each element is an interpolated function by `Interpolation[]`.

```
A[t_]:=Table[Interpolation[list[i]],{i,1,n}]]
```

Can I evaluate the vector A for fixed time?

I tried to define the vector A like above defined, and evaluated it by:
    A[0.1]

But the output is the list of interpolation, but not the value of functions at 0.1.

I tried to evaluated for fixed time the generic element of the A, and it seems work.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Your matrix definition does not depend upon $t$.  Please fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [`Composition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html) and [`Through`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Through.html). Using Jack's list of interpolation functions:

```
list = Table[{θ, Sin[n θ]}, {n, 1, 3}, {θ, 0, 2 π, 2 π/20}];
{f1, f2, f3} = Interpolation /@ list;
```

Then, you can define `A` as:

```
A = Through @* {f1, f2, f3};
```

Check:

```
A[.1] //N
```

> {0.0999854, 0.203017, 0.32276}

Same result

Comment: Thanks Carl Woll your solution it's that I need;)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide `list` so I'll make a simple one.

```
list = Table[{θ, Sin[n θ]}, {n, 1, 3}, {θ, 0, 2 π, 2 π/20}];

ListLinePlot[list]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now make a table of interpolated function from `list`.

```
{f1, f2, f3} = Interpolation[#] & /@ list
```

Define `A[t]` in terms of the functions

```
A[t_] := {f1[t], f2[t], f3[t]}

A[0.1] // N
(* {0.0999854, 0.203017, 0.32276} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution work, but need a manual definition element of A[t]. In my case is a disanvantage, but this method it is useful the same ;)

Answer (score 2):

@plus91, change your solution a litle bit and it works

```
    list = Table[{θ, Sin[n θ]}, {n, 1, 3}, {θ, 0, 2 π, 2 π/20}];

    A[t_] = Table[Interpolation[list[[i]]][t], {i, 1, 3}]

    A[0.1]

    (*   {0.0999854, 0.203017, 0.32276}  *)
```

Comment: Thx for your solution ;)